# Query with OR/AND inside OR/AND condition with Elasticsearch 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch

Need Help.

How to do Query in Elasticsearch like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  tableA WHERE 
tableA.clm1 IN ('A','B') 
AND 
(tableA.clm2 IN ('C', 'D') OR tableA.clm3 IN ('E','F'))
OR 
tableA.clm4 = 'Z'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

1. must/filter clause -- works like "AND". must calculates scores and filter
   only selects documents.
2. should clause - works line OR

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [  
        {
          "term": {
            "clm4.keyword": {
              "value": "Z"
            }
          }
        },  -- OR
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "clm1.keyword": [
                    "A",
                    "B"
                  ]
                }
              },  --AND
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "clm2.keyword": [
                          "C",
                          "D"
                        ]
                      }
                    }, --OR
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "clm3.keyword": [
                          "E",
                          "F"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Side note: You should prefer `filter` instead of `must` when doing exact match queries